# Viewing Server-Sent Events in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

[SSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) is a simple and straight-forward alternative to WebSockets when you need a one-way channel for events coming from the server.

In Chrome Dev Tools' Network tab, you can click the resource (url) where the SSE originates from and [view the stream in a tab of its own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46075339/200987). I cannot seem to find this functionality in Firefox.

Is there a simple way of viewing server-sent events in Firefox, that doesn't require me to change the source code (inserting logging statements)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox (as of version 67) does not support this feature yet. Though there is an enhancement request for this filed at https://bugzil.la/1405706.

Comment: Thanks. Seems there is releatively fresh activity in that thread, so maybe this will happen.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox 82 and onwards [should be able](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/Inspecting_server-sent_events) to show SSE messages in the Network > Response tab of the file which is sending those events.

Comment: Thanks. Got your other answer :) https://superuser.com/a/1619341/69121