# Is Called Rest Service Webflux or Not

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

How can I make sure the service I called WebFlux or Blocking service from Chrome Developer Tools? I've compared from network tab, looks like that,

[Blocking Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akn9E.png)

[WebFlux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2PlU.png)

Only transfer-encoding is different. When i call these services both services says `response waiting....` How can i be sure flux response is really `pushback`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring 5 uses SSE (Server Sent Events) to maintain the conection with the client and continue to send events when the controller returns a Flux or Mono Types. So the way to check if the server is using webflux is checking if it is using server sent events.
Here is a post which explains how to see it in google chrome explorer

[Debugging HTML5 Server-Sent Events in-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956243/debugging-html5-server-sent-events-in-browser)